# Issues with passing PHP echo in form through POST method

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<form method="POST" name="send"
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo ($pro->title;?)">
</form>
```

I dont want people to see the hidden informations , Is this the best way to pass the variable over to my controller?

This the code in my controller

```
$this->email->subject('subject '.$_POST['title'].' ' );
```

Thank you!

Comment: FYI, users can still modify hidden fields using e.g. firebug. If you want to avoid this, store the value in the session instead of a hidden field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" name="send"
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo ($pro->title;?)">
```

should be

```
<form method="POST" name="send">
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo $pro->title; ?>" />
```

For this i will suggest you to use `SESSION` because `hidden` fields can be changed.

Comment: And you have to make the input selve closing. so instead of `<input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo ($pro->title;?)">` it will then be `<input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo ($pro->title;?)" />`   (note the forward slash at the end)

Comment: You could also get rid of the brackets at the `echo`.

Comment: Closing an HTML Tag is just necessary if you chose a doctype which insists on it.

Comment: Hey thanks @jhonraymos, Tried that fix , i think the problem is with $this->email->subject('subject '.$_POST['title'].' ' ); the controller? :O

Comment: And is it possible to retrieve the data from controller if i use session?

Comment: @RainbowHat yes it is possible But i don't know how because i don't use `codeigniter`

Comment: you need to set the data in a session variable like this $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in_user', $login); and you need to retrieve that data in a controller like this way $logged_in = $this->session->userdata("logged_in_user");.......you can use $logged_in variable as your wish...........